# How to get size of single map tile in mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am using mapbox iOS SDK for offline map feature. Before downloading the tiles (while map panning, zooming etc.) I need to check how many tiles is uploaded and what is the total downloaded map tile size. I wrote the code:

```
 for (RMTileCache *cache in mapV.tileCache.tileCaches) {
        if([cache isKindOfClass:[RMDatabaseCache class]])
        {
            RMDatabaseCache *fileCache = (RMDatabaseCache *) cache;
            double megabytes = (double)fileCache.fileSize/1024/1024;
            self.title = [baseTitle stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@":%.1lf MB",megabytes]];
        }
    }
```

Does it not frequently calculate the size? Is there any other solution? Please help out.

Comment: Removed the xcode tag, as this question doesn't involve the IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood what you need it and when..

You have the 2 following delegate methods that would help in terms of numbers:
     
   
-(void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBeginBackgroundCacheWithCount:(NSUInteger)tileCount forTileSource:(id<RMTileSource>)tileSource
   
   
-(void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBackgroundCacheTile:(RMTile)tile withIndex:(NSUInteger)tileIndex ofTotalTileCount:(NSUInteger)totalTileCount